# \RedeclareSectionCommand in combination with \addsec

Tags: koma-script

How can I change the behavior of `\addsec`? Using this code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\part{Part}
\addchap{First Title}
    \addsec{First Section}
    \addsec{Next Section}
%
\part{Part}
\chapter{First Real Chapter}
    \section{First Real Section}
    \section{Second Real Section}
\end{document}
```

I get in the TOC

[image]

But I would like to have the unnumbered First Section in line with the First Real Section. Using `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5.5em]{addsec}` e.g. is not working (as also remarked in the manual at 21.8).

Answer (score 3):

Use option `toc=indentunnumbered` either as class option

`\documentclass[toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}`

or using

`\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}`

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\addchap{First Title}
\addsec{First Section}
\addsec{Next Section}
\part{Part}
\chapter{First Real Chapter}
\section{First Real Section}
\section{Second Real Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should sometimes test all the options which are available. I got it.